# REPLACE INTO table in mysql query optimization

Tags: mysql, replace, query-optimization

I have below query which is taking nearly 70min for the completion.

The record counts of tables:

- demo.HIST_MARKETING_COMM_DISCREPANCIES -- ~400K  Records
- demo.VW_2AND3_LETTER_COUNTRY_DETAILS  -- 260  Records
- DG_ORG_DETAILS_DIM -- 20  Records

My MySQL server config:  2 vCPUs, 6GB RAM, 300GB Disk size

```
replace into demo.mt_mkt_comm_base_tbl
SELECT c.org_id 
     , c.org_name 
     , IFNULL(GETINITCAP(hcd.cntry_name), a.prmry_reside_country_code) country_name
     , a.*
  FROM demo.hist_marketing_comm_discrepancies a
  LEFT 
  JOIN demo.vw_2and3_letter_country_details hcd 
    ON hcd.cntry_code2 = a.prmry_reside_country_code
  LEFT 
  JOIN demo.dg_org_details_dim c 
    ON a.org_id = c.org_id
 WHERE a.active_flag = 'y'
   AND a.breach_indicator IS NOT NULL
```

Explain plan for the above:

[image]

Seeking some help to improve the performance of query, i'm even fine to scale my server configuration also.

I have used index as below

1. A composite Index on ( ACTIVE_FLAG, BREACH_INDICATOR, MAIL_DATE) in hist_marketing_comm_discrepancies, Even MAIL_DATE is removed also same composite index is being used, so kept it.
   KEY `idx_composite_key` (`ACTIVE_FLAG`,`BREACH_INDICATOR`,`MAIL_DATE`)
2. Index on CNTRY_CODE2
3. Index on ORG_ID

Now the explain plan is as below

[image: Explain plan after indexing]

And query is giving the result ~20min, is there anyway query execution time further can be reduced.

I have resized innodb_buffer_pool_size,
Before modification it was 108M, I have modified that to 3000M, Now the entire replace query completes in ~2min.

To change the setting is done in the [mysqld] section of the my.cnf file. And you must restart mysqld to get it to take effect. (in ubuntu you can locate my.cnf file in /etc folder)

Comment: What's the point for the `left join`s to start with? They are not filtering anything (since they are *left* joins), and you are not using any columns from the tables in the resultset.

Comment: I haven't pasted all the columns in select statement, but i need to join tables to get some columns, to make it clear i have edited my question by adding the columns i'm getting from the joining columns.

Comment: I cannot see that GETINITCAP does anything useful here, other than slow down the query

Comment: GETINITCAP is a simple function which capitalize the first letter in each word of column.

Answer (score 1):

make sure all these fields are indexed:
cntry_code2
prmry_reside_country_code
org_id
breach_indicator
active_flag
it will reduce the cardinality of your problem.
remove the IFNULL and filter your query afterward.
for sure scaling your server would help but your config and amount of data you have shouldn’t be this slow.

Answer (score 1):

Let's back up a step.  What is the purpose of this `REPLACE`?  How much of the table is being replaced?

If it is practical to build a fresh copy of the table, then 'swap' it into place, that is likely to be much faster.  (Cf `RENAME TABLE`; I can discuss further if needed.)

If it is practical to do the "replacing" piecemeal, then that could be much less invasive.  (See techniques in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks )

Please note that `REPLACE` is implemented as `DELETE` + `INSERT`.  As such, you destroy auto_inc values, and work harder than with IODKU, so...

If you stick with `REPLACE .. SELECT ..`, then consider changing to `INSERT INTO t .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..`.  It is likely to be faster.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#optimal_reload_of_a_table discusses both the full table replacement and the use of `RENAME TABLE`.

**Indexes**

These may help some:

```
a:  (active_flag, breach_indicator, org_id, prmry_reside_country_code)
c:  (org_id, org_name)
hcd:  (cntry_code2, cntry_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for the details, I'm using REPLACE to update the record if my key present else insert the record. I'm going thru the links you have given

Comment: I have updated my questions with explain plan on adding the indexes. Can you check if there is any way for improvement.

Comment: @VenkatJ - Notice how the _estimated_ number of rows went down from 386K to 196K.  This indicates that the `INDEX` _may_ have helped.  The 3 indexes I suggested are each likely to help _some_.  When adding `INDEX(a,b)`, it is usually beneficial to drop `INDEX(a)` since it is a prefix of the new index.